# More then 7 characters and encyption's dont match C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I have a password hashing method in C# that I'm trying to port it to PHP for my website, which will allow both my website and application to use the passwords from the same database (application requires a website account to use). The problem is, once the password gets over 7 characters in length, the result is different in php then what I'm getting in C#, but any password less then 8 characters, matches the C# encryption exactly.

here my method in C#

```
    public static byte[] PassEncode(byte[] pass)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int num = 0x79707367; // starting num
        for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; i++)
        {
            num = PassLame(num);
            a = num % 0xFF;
            pass[i] ^= (byte)a;
        }

        return pass;
    }

    private static int PassLame(int num)
    {
        int c = (num >> 16) & 0xffff;
        int a = num & 0xffff;

        c *= 0x41a7;
        a *= 0x41a7;
        a += ((c & 0x7fff) << 16);

        if (a < 0)
        {
            a &= 0x7fffffff;
            a++;
        }

        a += (c >> 15);

        if (a < 0)
        {
            a &= 0x7fffffff;
            a++;
        }

        return a;
    }
```

And my methods in PHP:

```
    function PassEncode($pass)
    {
        $a = 0;
        $num = 0x79707367;
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($pass); $i++)
        {
            $num = PassLame($num);
            $a = $num % 0xFF;
            $pass[$i] ^= $a;
        }

        return $pass;
    }

    function  PassLame($num)
    {
        $c = ($num >> 16) & 0xffff;
        $a = $num & 0xffff;

        $c *= 0x41a7;
        $a *= 0x41a7;
        $a += (($c & 0x7fff) << 16);

        if ($a < 0)
        {
            $a &= 0x7fffffff;
            $a++;
        }

        $a += ($c >> 15);

        if ($a < 0)
        {
            $a &= 0x7fffffff;
            $a++;
        }

        return $a;
    }
```

The bytes I'm using is for the word "testing".

```
bytes = ([0]=> 116 [1]=> 101 [2]=> 115 [3]=> 116 [4]=> 105 [5]=> 110 [6]=> 103)
```

When I plug these in, the 8th digit returned (and beyond if using a larger pass) are a lot different then in C#./ My results

**C#:**

```
[0]=> int(98) [1]=> int(151) [2]=> int(135) [3]=> int(134) [4]=> int(66) [5]=> int(181) [6]=> int(113)
```

**PHP:**

```
[0]=> int(98) [1]=> int(151) [2]=> int(135) [3]=> int(134) [4]=> int(66) [5]=> int(181) [6]=> int(11)
```

Can anyone help me solve this? I'm using a 32bit webserver and compiling my application in 32bit as well.

Comment: Have you tried to check num every each iteration?

Comment: Yes, after the 7th itteration, the number produced from the PassLame() is different then the other applications

Comment: So what value do you pass to PassLame? Now that you know that things will be a lot easier to debug. No you can just call PassLame with that value. And then print $a and $c when you change them and figure out when there is a difference

Comment: Why do you want to use that function instead of something good, like bcrypt?

Comment: Because the hash needs to be reversible

Answer (score 0):

I believe PHP handles integer overflow by converting the value to float.  That is almost certainly the cause of your problem.

You could write custom functions for the arithmetic that check for overflow and mimic c#'s wraparound behavior.

Comment: so should i be converting to long instead?

Comment: @Wilson212 I don't think PHP supports64-bit integers in a 32-bit platform, but if it did, that wouldn't help.  It would just make the difference appear at 16 characters instead of 8.  You probably need PHP functions that do c#-style arithmetic.